# LUIS.AI - moving to a paid plan

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

My chatbot has been down for the last few days (quota for free conversations has been exceeded), and I am seriously thinking of moving to a paid plan.
Please see attached the error returned when initiating a conversation from emulator.
The documentation to move to a paid plan is not clear at all. 
Can someone please list the steps that I have to take or pinpoint me to the proper documentation please?

Technology : MS Botframework with nodejs (luis,qna,language detection)

I suppose I have to create a key in azure and insert it in the luis.ai app. But searching for LUIS in azure returns no result.

Grateful if you guys can help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Svy.png)

Comment: Hope this details explanation would satisfy all of your questions and confusions.Let me know if you have any more concern

Comment: Are you using the authoring key? At first I was using this key which only allowed 1000 transactions/month. But you can create a free tier service which can support 10,000 transactions/month. So you don't need to jump to a paid tier if your usage won't exceed that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to implement `LUIS` on azure portal and want to know more about `pricing` but cannot get LUIS on azure portal.

Well,Follow the below steps to know how you would implement that.

**LUIS :**

*`Step 1:`*

For `LUIS` go to your azure portal then and click on `Create a resource` finally search by `Language Understanding`  you would get that. See the below screen shot:

[image]

*`Step 2:`*

Once you type `Language Understanding` you would get below Option. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Once you are done with setup you should click `Keys and Endpoint` to call from your application. See the screen shot below:

[image]

though correct official document reference you would get there also given here as well.

[1. `Luis Official Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis)

[2. `Pricing`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/)

> For your information pricing varies based on `Region`. Usual price is:
>
> You can do 50 transaction per second  and have to pay $1.5 per 1000
>   (one thousand transaction)

**QnA Maker :**

For QnA maker you could also follow above steps. See the following screen shot:

[image]

1. [QnA Maker Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/tutorials/create-publish-query-in-portal)
2. [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/qna-maker/)

**Language Detection:**

If you plan to detect your language you could use `Text Analytics` which provides `advanced natural language processing` and `identify the language of the text with language detection` See the screen shot below:

[image]

1. [Language Detection Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/overview)
2. [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/text-analytics/)

> **Note:** All the service has language support for [`Node.js`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/sdk-authoring?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-nodejs). Hope this would help.